# How to retain Gregorian date format of date input if region OS is Thai

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date string pulled from Excel which I'm trying to parse. Said date is originally in Gregorian format. Is there any way to retain this even after using `TryParse`/`TryParseExact`?

**Note:** Since our end-users are from Thailand, I'm doing this while my machine's region is set to Thai. Hence, my system date as of this post is `"12/7/2561"`.

Suppose I have the following string input in Gregorian `M/d/yyyy` format:

```
string validDate = "7/15/2018"
```

When I initially tried parsing this using `DateTime.TryParseExact`, it gave me `15/7/2561`.

I've tried the following methods listed in these links, particularly the `CreateSpecificCulture`:

1. [MSDN: Convert Thailand DateTime TO English DateTime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/24b59a67-4da0-44b7-9d73-e9f0bc6bcef0/convert-thailand-datetime-to-english-datetime?forum=csharpgeneral)
2. [ASP.NET forums: DateTime issue while converting from thai culture to english culture](https://forums.asp.net/t/2120318.aspx?DateTime%20issue%20while%20converting%20from%20thai%20culture%20to%20english%20culture)

Here's my code right now:

```
public DateTime? ConvertThaiToGregorian(string text, string dateFormat)
{
    /// Note: Thailand uses the Thai Buddhist calendar, which is 543 years ahead of 
    ///       the Gregorian calendar. 
    /// dateFormat here is "M/d/yyyy".

    DateTime convertedDate;

    // Create Thai CultureInfo
    IFormatProvider thCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("th-TH");

    // Parse date = returns "15/7/2018"...
    DateTime.TryParseExact(text, dateFormat, thCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate);

    // Create en-US CultureInfo
    IFormatProvider engCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    // Parse date back to US format = gives me "01/01/0544"...
    DateTime.TryParseExact(convertedDate.ToString(), dateFormat, engCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate);

    return convertedDate;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure about "parsing using DateTime.TryParseExact, it gives me 15/7/2561", when you parse it with the `engCulture`? because from the code you've shown it looks like you're purposefully interpreting it as a Thai date before parsing the string representation of *that* in en-US culture.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed explaining a few points. Kindly see my updated question. `15/7/2561` was the first result I got when I initially tried to parse it using `TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you understand how CultureInfo gets the DateTime from a string, the bare minimum requirement is in what culture date string is, but server or operating system shouldn't matter if string is parsed correct. Operating system will interfere only if culture isn't specified when string is parsed.

C# fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wdDlts

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string thaiBudistDate = "12/7/2561";

        // US format
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(thaiBudistDate, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + provider + "' in 'en-US' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );

        // Thai Culture
        provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th-TH");
        date = DateTime.Parse(thaiBudistDate, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + provider + "' in 'th-TH' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );

        // Thai Culture format! M/d/yyyy
        provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th-TH");
        var format = "M/d/yyyy";
        date = DateTime.ParseExact(thaiBudistDate, format, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + provider + "' in 'th-TH' format specified 'M/d/yyyy' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );

        // Thai Culture format d/M/yyyy 
        provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th-TH");
        format = "d/M/yyyy";
        date = DateTime.ParseExact(thaiBudistDate, format, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + provider + "' in 'th-TH' format specified 'd/M/yyyy' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );

        // Using Gregorian time
        string usaDate = "12/7/2018";
        // US Culture
        provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        date = DateTime.Parse(usaDate, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + usaDate + "' in 'en-Us' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );


        // You got the point, dones't matter what provider you use! Hope this will help you undestand how wondows Culture works
        usaDate = "12/7/2018";
        // Thai Culture
        provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th-TH");
        date = DateTime.Parse(usaDate, provider);
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: '" + usaDate + "' in 'th-TH' => Day: " + date.Day + " Month: " + date.Month + " Year: " + date.Year );

    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the very detailed explanation and samples! =) This is the first time I learned about `GetCultureInfo`; the samples I read previously only used `CreateSpecificCulture`.

Comment: Forgot to add: these also worked with `TryParseExact`.

Comment: Working with date formats across globe is a bitch :) glad it helped.

Comment: Tell me about it. =)) This was the first time I worked on something like this. A very good learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the datetime converted to Thai culture (where day, month and year properties are correctly set) I think its enough to format it again to Datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy") in case you want the string representation.